# Why is my program running fine in release mode, but failing in debug mode?

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.5, release

My program is running fine when it is in RELEASE mode, but when I run it in DEBUG mode, it fails on these lines of code:

```
string l_strFileDir = @"C:\Program Files\Sil\Q 5.2\";

Process scriptProc = new Process();
scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = @"USB_VID_PID.exe";
scriptProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = l_strFileDir;
scriptProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
scriptProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

scriptProc.Start();

string l_strFilePath =  l_strFileDir + @"\out.txt";
```

The error is:

> Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

and it gives me that stack trace.

**edit:**
the .exe file not necessary need to be in the debug folder because I wrote a full path.

when the program break in the exception it wrote that the file was not found in another path- not the path I wrote in the code.

the exception occurs in the line with the Start command.

there is no double backslash in my path

[this is the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d8wC.png)

Comment: When you break on the exception, what is the file you're application is trying to "find"?  This should be pretty easy to figure out.

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough details. On which line is the exception occurring?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of you BIN folders? Does one have "USB_VID_PID.exe" and the other not?

Comment: `l_strFilePath` will be an invalid file path.

Comment: As @MatthewWhited mentioned, `l_strFilePath` will be `C:\Program Files\Sil\Q 5.2\\out.txt` based on the code you provided. Notice the extra backslash between `Q 5.2` and `out.txt`.

Comment: @LewsTherin: But that variable is never used. Also, depending how you use the path, the double backslash might not actually cause any problems anyway. Some functions will work just fine with it (though I can't name off top of head, I just know I have seen it before)

Comment: drop the leading slash on the file name and use `Path.Combine(l_strFileDir, "out.txt")` instead.

Comment: and that maybe true @musefan... but we don't have an entire application and we don't know the line number that is causing the exception.

Comment: Project > Properties > Debug tab.  You need to untick the "Prefer 32-bit" option for both the Debug and the Release configuration.  More about the file system redirector that redirects c:\program files to c:\program files (x86) in [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant, the redirect you referenced doesn't effect full paths to `program files`.

Comment: And Like Hans you are wrong @PeterDuniho.

Comment: you are welcome to test it yourself... Here is a simple program... feel free to target x86. 

    `if (Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Program Files\").Length !=
        Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\Program Files (X86)\").Length)
        Console.WriteLine("We don't match!!!");
    Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: BTW, you would have a point if OP was doing this... `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `USB_VID_PID.exe` is not in your debug folder.  Either add the entire path to `.StartInfo.FileName` or add the EXE to the debug folder.

```
scriptProc.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(l_strFileDir, @"USB_VID_PID.exe");
```

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)

> When UseShellExecute is false, the WorkingDirectory property is not
>   used to find the executable. Instead, its value applies to the process
>   that is started and only has meaning within the context of the new
>   process.

Comment: I doubt the OP will ever confirm, but I would say this answer clearly shows what the problem is and why it is occurring.

Comment: lol... down voted for the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

DEBUG and RELEASE compilation result in code output in different directories. You probably try to create a `Process` object on a file, that simply doesn't exist. Make sure, your file is in the right target directory or improve the path information to the file.

Comment: someone is having a bad few days... lots of down votes without reason for the last several days.